# Умные сети - где ставить кавычки

Tags: орфография

В сочетаниях "умные сети", "умные счетчики", "умные города" и т.д. - кавычками выделяются оба слова или только слово "умные"?
А как быть с сочетанием "спящий полицейский"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще, в кавычки берется то, что употреблено в переносном или иностаказательном значении. В данном случае слово "умный". А насчет полицейского, Вы имели в виду "лежачего полицейского"? Тут, мне кажется, в кавычки берутся оба слова, потому что в переносном значении употреблено все словосочетание.